# fix Android : Fatal Exception main

Tags: android

I am a beginner at Android Development. This is the first time I am ever posting on stackoverflow, so forgive me if I make any noob mistakes. I have completed a partial version of my first app. I just want to run it on an Android Device and see if it works and functions properly. I have no errors in my code. I got the FATAL Exception: main to go away.

However, the functionality is not working as I want it to. I can't tell what the problem is. I want the CE1s to be displayed in the ce TextView when i click the button. The code is have written is not doing it.

Here is the MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText course1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Course1);
    final EditText credit1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    final EditText grade1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText13);
    final Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final TextView ce = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    String grade_1 = grade1.getText().toString();
    double credit_1 = Double.parseDouble(credit1.getText().toString());
    double CE1=0;
    if (grade_1 == "A")
        CE1 = 4*credit_1;
    final String CE1s = Double.toString(CE1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
        ce.setText(CE1s);
        }

    });
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }


    }
}
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rutgersgpacalculator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.rutgersgpacalculator.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the logcat

```
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785): Process: com.example.rutgersgpacalculator, PID: 24785
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rutgersgpacalculator/com.example.rutgersgpacalculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at com.example.rutgersgpacalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:31)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
05-24 12:41:55.513: E/AndroidRuntime(24785):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is evident from the stacktrace. You are trying to parse a `String` into a double and it is failing because the `String` to parse is a `""`. This is probably happening because you are trying to parse an empty `EditText.

Answer (score 1):

`credit1` is empty in onCreate, so the call to `parseDouble` gets passed an empty string, which it doesn't like. Use `TextUtils.isEmpty()` first to check if the text is empty before you parse it.

```
String text = credit1.getText().toString();
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
    // call parseDouble in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wann to compare strings,  you have to use `if (grade_1.equals ("A"))` instead of `if (grade_1 == 1)`